# How to interconnect GCP with Oracle cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, google-cloud-networking

I want to connect GCP infrastructure with OCI infrastructure so that all the services can communicate on the private network instead of allowing public IP which the traffic get comes.

as per my findings, I found **Equinix** can provide what I'm looking for but again that's a totally different thing, and introducing it in the current environment is impossible.

isn't there any service that GCP or OCI provide for the same ?

Comment: Your question lacks details. Which services are you trying to connect? Typically, you configure a VPN to link two private networks together. Both Oracle and Google Cloud offer VPNs. However, a correct answer requires more information.

Comment: @kingfateh Khan If your issue has been resolved please post the answer; so, that it will be useful for other community members.

Comment: Hi @AbhijithChitrapu
yes, the issue was resolved. I ended up taking support from the Equinix team and they set up a VPN between OCI to GCP which works normally. but I was looking for a better solution like a direct connection between  OCI to GCP without any third party. as per OCI and GCP as well it's not possible right now but GCP is working on this so just waiting  when they going to introduce  that service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into using a NaaS provider like [PacketFabric](https://packetfabric.com/cloud-router), [Megaport](https://www.megaport.com/services/megaport-cloud-router/), or even I think [Equinix](https://www.equinix.com/interconnection-services/equinix-fabric) has a solution to connect Multi Clouds.

You would essentially use Google Interconnect and Oracle FastConnect with a [NaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_as_a_service) in the middle providing the link.

It depends on what you are looking for but if you are looking for a private, secure, and low latency connection between Google and OCI, go with a NaaS, otherwise, a VPN over the internet should work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Network Edge solution from Equinix. This is essentially a Virtual Device that allows to interconnect to multiple Clouds.

https://docs.equinix.com/en-us/Content/Interconnection/NE/landing-pages/NE-landing-main.htm